# Attempting to pass additional argument to a switcher library results in "'NoneType' object is not callable" error

Tags: python, switch-statement, nonetype

I'm trying to pass two arguments to the switcher function, then use one of those arguments to define the switch case, and one of them to be passed to the case function. The portion of the code I provided has the function for one of the cases, the rest are similarly formatted.

I'm not sure if this is the right approach to creating this function, or why I am getting this error.

```
right = 1
def Default():
    print('Something went wrong :(')
def Right(duration):
    pyautogui.moveTo(1123,899) #Right Arrow Button
    pyautogui.mouseDown()
    time.sleep(duration)
    pyautogui.mouseUp()
    time.sleep(0.03)
def Move(direction,duration):
    switcher = {
        1: Right(duration) ,
        2: Left ,
        3: Down ,
        4: DiagonalUp 
        }
    return switcher.get(direction, Default)()
x = 2.5
Move(right,x)
```

The error I get is:
line 48, in Move
    return switcher.get(direction, Default)()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

I do not get this error when I don't include the duration variable at all in the code.

Comment: looks like `Default` is `None`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the function for the default case. It is in the original code that was giving me the issue. I've added it into the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions that don't return, implicitly return None. So this:

```
def Default():
    print('Something went wrong :(')
```

is the same as this:

```
def Default():
    print('Something went wrong :(')
    return None
```

Which means your dict `get` tries to do this:

```
return switcher.get(direction, None)()
```

Since there is no `None` key in `switcher`, it returns `None` and then `None()` is exectued... which is not valid since `callable(None)` = `False`

You need `Default` to actually return a legitimate `switcher` key or `raise` an exception.

Comment: I'm new to python so I apologise in advance if I didn't follow correctly, I changed the "Default" function to return 1, which I believe should be a valid key for the switcher. However now it runs through all of the cases sequentially instead of just running one case.